# How to get the specific data in a response inside controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code of login. Getting the data response from hosting is okay and ng-repeat in a view once it's validate shows all the data. But I want to make a validation for it, I just want to get the specific data ex:username in a data then compare to the previously user input. But when I try to get the specific entity like username or password in a controller, Undefined variable shows to my alert just to figure it was selected. How will I able to do that? Thanks to anyone who can help me to solve this.

```js
$scope.login = function (user) {
    UserFactory.login($scope.users).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Student Profile" + angular.toJson(response));
        $scope.user = response.data;
        alert($scope.user.username);
        alert($scope.user.password);
    }, function (err) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
            template: 'Please check your credentials!'
        });
    });
};
```

```html
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="login(user)">Login</button>
<div class="list card">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-repeat="item in user">
             id: {{item.user_id}} 
             firstname: {{item.firstname}} 
             lastname: {{item.lastname}} 
             token: {{item.access_token}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: prior to the existing alerts, add another alert: `alert(response.data);` so you can inspect what's actually coming back from the server.

Comment: `console.log(response)` to check what you have got.

Comment: Show UserFactory.login() --- I suspect something there is not ok

Comment: I've only got  alert[object, object].